# Как в TcxDBPivotGrid при раскраске грида получить значение из произвольной колонки?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Есть кросс-таблица `cxDBPivotGrid1`, в которой несколько полей группируются в столбцы по значению поля DB. В поле «BACK_COLOR» хранится цвет, в который нужно раскрасить ячейки в группе. Раскрашиваю грид в событии CustomDrawCell. Если я пытаюсь получить значение поля «BACK_COLOR» через `cxDBPivotGrid1BACK_COLOR.Values[AViewInfo.RowIndex]`, мне всегда возвращается значение из одной и той же группы, вне зависимости от того, в какой группе находится ячейка, которую нужно раскрасить. Если я пытаюсь воспользоваться `cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet.FieldByName('BACK_COLOR')`, она отрабатывает только на ячейке, в которой установлен курсор. Возможно ли как-то получить значение произвольного поля из текущей записи?
Пример исходной таблицы:

```
+--+---------+-------+-----+-----+----------+
|ID|ITEM_NAME|   DB  |VALUE|TREND|BACK_COLOR|
+--+---------+-------+-----+-----+----------+
| 1|Продажи  |NEPTUNE| 5000|  +5%|  0x88FF88|
| 2|Звонки   |NEPTUNE|  200| +25%|  0x88FF88|
| 3|Потери   |NEPTUNE|   20|  -3%|  0x88FF88|
| 4|Продажи  |PLUTO  | 7000|   0%|  0xFFFFFF|
| 5|Звонки   |PLUTO  |  180|  -5%|  0xFF8888|
| 6|Потери   |PLUTO  |   18|  +5%|  0xFF8888|
| 7|Продажи  |MARS   |12000|  -1%|  0xFF8888|
| 8|Звонки   |MARS   |  250|   0%|  0xFFFFFF|
| 9|Потери   |MARS   |   31|   0%|  0xFFFFFF|
+--+---------+-------+-----+-----+----------+
```

Должно получиться так:
[image: Как должно быть]

А выходит так:
[image: Как получается]

Comment: в параметрах события-то ничего полезного нет?

Comment: В параметрах события есть AViewInfo. Если я пытаюсь получить значение поля «BACK_COLOR» через cxDBPivotGrid1BACK_COLOR.Values[AViewInfo.RowIndex], мне всегда возвращается значение из одной и той же группы, вне зависимости от того, в какой группе находится ячейка, которую нужно раскрасить.

Comment: `AViewInfo.CrossCell.Row.RecordIndex` там еще что-то такое есть.

Comment: Возвращает то же самое, что и AViewInfo.RowIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таки нашёл ответ сам:

```pascal
var wFld:=Sender.GetFieldByName(FieldName);
    if wFld=nil then exit;
    if wFld.Area=faData then
      fValue:= AViewInfo.CrossCell.GetCrossCellValue(wFld)
    else
      fValue:=wFld.Values[AViewInfo.RowIndex];
```

Получается, для полей в Data area и за его пределами способы получения значения разные!